# Move an SVG element across Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

How do you move an svg in one div, to an svg in another div?

Try to move the red circle to the left.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a6da/).

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">
        <svg id="leftSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <svg id="rightSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Ultimately, a working base proof of concept of the project can be found [here](http://specialorange.org/sof/) (we are teaching fractions with music), but we are trying to implement the idea of a "factory" where beats are created, and can be dragged onto a measure.  Given that we have many views, we utilize backbone, which uses html templates from _underscore.

Since we are using cutting edge HTML5 Audio, we are limited to Chrome only, so the Firefox problems shouldn't be an issue.

Any other suggestions? like :

- an SVG that covers that page, and has a z-index of 1
- a combination with JQueryUI
- have the SVG follow the drag, and when drop, recreate it in the dropped SVG area?

Comment: You can't do this with two different SVGs as the handlers, elements, etc are completely separate. You need a single element.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  updated,  can you think of other solutions?   PS, thanks for the help on the fiddle!

Comment: Here's a pure SVG solution with two `rect`s as background: http://jsfiddle.net/6a6da/34/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff good, but seems to have problems in FF 20.0.1

Comment: yeah that's going to be really difficult and hacky to do with two different svgs.  in theory it could be done by observing mouse events globally, and tying that observation to the svg drag events, and creating a new circle in the left svg when the cirlce in the right svg vanished, and moving it with the mouse, etc... it would be an unbelievable pain and you should definitely try to come up with another solutions like the one Lars suggested.

Comment: @Jonah , updated to include the project to help expand idea possibilities and limitations.

Comment: So the firefox problems aren't an issue? ;)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff   You are funny, plus i would love to meet you, I liked your dissertation btw.   If im ever in Germany, Ill be sure to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an attempt (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/thegreatmichael/7tmn9/1/) in which I'm basically noticing that you've mode into the space of the other svg (negative x) and then i redraw the appropriate svg there.

```
drag.on("dragend", function(){
    if (d3.select(this).attr("cx") < 0) {
        var newX = d3.select(this).attr("cx");
        newX = parseInt(left.attr('width'))+parseInt(newX);
        var newY = d3.select(this).attr("cy");
        console.log('move it to: ', newX);
        left.append('g')
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', '10')
        .attr('cx', newX)
        .attr('cy', newY)
        .attr('id', 'left'+newX)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
    }
});
```